# Strictly monotone functions and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta, monotone-functions

> Let $f : X \to I$ be a strictly monotone surjective function mapping
>   $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then
>   is $f$ necessarily continuous?

Without loss of generality assume that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Let $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose there exists some $f(a) \in (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x))$ and $f(b) \in (f(x), f(x) + \epsilon)$. Then taking $\delta = \min(x-a,b-x)$ we obtain $$z \in (x - \delta, x + \delta) \implies z \in (a,b) \implies f(z) \in (f(a), f(b)) \subseteq (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon)$$
so that $f$ is continuous.

Suppose there does not exist $f(a) \in (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x))$. Since $I$ is an interval there is no $f(x') < f(x)$. So there is no $x' < x$ where $x' \in X$. So we can set $a = x - 1$ in the above proof. Similarly if there does not exist $f(b) \in (f(x), f(x) + \epsilon)$, we can set $b = x + 1$ in the above proof.

Is this proof correct? Or can $f$ possibly be discontinuous?

Comment: Can you use that a function is continuous iff the inverse image of an open set is open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous, but you can give a much simpler argument:

if $f$ is discontinuous at some point $x$, then $f(x^-)<f(x^+)$ (since it is strictly increasing, the two limits exist). Moreover, $f(x)\in[f(x^-),f(x^+)]$ but $f$ takes no other values in the open interval $(f(x^-),f(x^+))$ (either $f(x)$ is there or not, but no other point). So $f$ is not onto.

Comment: So $f(x)$ does not belongs to an interval $(f(x^-), f(x^+))$ ?